# How can I get the highest value from a dictionary nested in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

the following is a list from a small blind auction program i am writing. After the last bid, I need to loop through all the bids in the list and print out the highest one with the name of the bidder. How can I go about that? Any help?

```
bids = [{'don': 200}, {'alex': 400}, {'peter': 550}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the list according to the value in each dictionary and print out the last item:

```
bids = [{'don': 200}, {'alex': 400}, {'peter': 550}]
s = sorted(bids, key=lambda x:list(x.values())[0])
print(s[-1])

#{'peter': 550}
```

UPDATED:

```
bids = [{'don': 200}, {'alex': 400}, {'peter': 550}]
bids.sort(key=lambda x:list(x.values())[0], reverse=True)
print(f'The winner is {list(bids[0].keys())[0]} with a ${list(bids[0].values())[0]} bid.')

#The winner is peter with a $550 bid.
```

Comment: Thanks Pakpe. This also worked. But I needed the result printed in a formatted string. for example as follows: "The winner is Peter with a $550 bid".

Comment: @DonKalonji That's strange.  You did not indicate that anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `max` with a custom key function:

```
>>> next(iter(max(bids, key=lambda d: next(iter(d.values())))))
'peter'
```

The most annoying part of this is the `next(iter(...))` part of extracting the key/value from the dictionary.

Is there any reason you use this datastructure rather than a simple dictionary like `{'don': 200, 'alex': 400, 'peter': 550}`? In that case it would be easier:

```
>>> max(bids, key=lambda name: bids[name])
'peter'
```

Comment: I agree with @L3viathan you should actually rethink your data structure... With a list of tuples (name, bid), you can after use ```max(bids, key=operator.itemgetter(1))```

Comment: Thanks for the response, 
There was no specific reason I just wanted to explore other ways of doing it to solidify my understanding of nested dictionaries and lists) after I initially  had bids as a dictionary.

Basically I did it as follows:

bids = {}
name = input("What is your name: ")
price = int(input("Your bid:" ))

bids[name] = price 

And after the final bid, to get the highest bid and bidder I did this:

Comment: Part of an if/else statement:

elif new_bidder == "n":
    more_bidders = False
    clear()
    highest_bidder = max(bids, key=bids.get)
    all_bids = bids.values()
    max_bid = max(all_bids)
    print(f"The highest bidder is {highest_bidder} with R{max_bid}")

Answer (score 0):

I think using {'name':'bidername','bid': bid} makes it so easy. After that u can sort it and take the last one or you can iterate on bids and find the highest bid.

```
bids = [{'name': 'don', 'bid': 200}, {'name': 'alex', 'bid': 400}, {'name': 'peter', 'bid': 550}]

print(sorted(bids, key=lambda x: x['bid']))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get only highest value.

```py
bids = [{'don': 200}, {'alex': 400}, {'peter': 550}]

bidder = None
values = []

for bid in bids:
    for k, v in bid.items():
        values.append(v)

bidder = max(values)
print(bidder)
```